# Problem with LT3750 charging

Tags: capacitor, charger, capacitor-charging

I'm trying to build a flyback circuit to charge a 1uF cap to ~300, but am having a lot of issues.  I'm just following the data sheet diagram for a 300V 3A charger (see pic below).

I've never been able to get an output voltage of more than ~150V.  And after moving things around, output voltage will usually be ~8V.  The layout I followed is a combination of the data sheet recommendation and conversation with LT tech support.  Components pretty much follow the diagram below.

I've attached a picture of my very unprofessional circuit to see if maybe someone could point out a glaring problem I don't see.  Other LT3750 circuits I've seen online are usually on actual circuit boards, but I'm not quite sure how to go about getting that done.  Maybe someone could advise?

It's quite frustrating to fail at making a proven design work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

first of all make sure the **voltage rating** is D1 and C4 is much higher than 300V. For a capacitor, the voltage rating would be at least double of the operation voltage for safety.
Second, try to build a PCB to test your idea. I have experience to design a boost circuit using LT1930, from 3.7v to +-12v. I never be able to get a good output with breadboard, either very noisy or not enough output. After I deploy everything on a pcb board, the signal is so nice, clean and steady.

If you exactly follow the example in the datasheet, the best shot is using pcb. Please follow my suggestion: always using surface mount component(resistor,Capacitor), try to use **solder paste** for SMT. If you don't know how to use it, please search youtube "hotplate solder paste", you will find it is so easy. After I learned it, I very seldom use solder iron to solder chips. Believe me. It is amazing. The performance on pcb is so good. You will thank me. In your situation, you can start from easy one, choosing slightly big components for soldering.

By the way for starting of smd, you can check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHRabJupfSo
It is not a very good video, but good to start. I would find a chance to take the video if I populate a board next time.

Answer (score 1):

> Components pretty much follow the diagram below.

I hope they don't because that circuit diagram is wrong if you are using the DA2032 coilcraft transformer. This circuit diagram (below) matches the coilcraft DA2032-AL transformer (the one you appear to have fitted): -

[image]

In your diagram pins 6 and 7 are connected together but this will short one of the windings out: -

[image]

---

Footnote to people who post schematics that supposedly represent their actual circuit but don't - this wastes my time and their's

Answer (score 0):

your circuit has 2 times current sensed resistor [25mohm] vs 12mohm to reach 300v...your circuit goes into constant current limit and cuts down voltage loop regulation by half and thus you will only see 150v max output....run your circuit in ltspice 4 and tune Rs and voltage feedback Rvout/Rdcm resistor gain ratio...and you will be able to regulate any output voltage you want....

Comment: Current sense will not affect final output voltage. Save for extreme cases.